# Difficulty in understanding the meaning of sample space in probability:

Tags: probability

In my textbook, the definition of sample space is given as "A set S that consists of all possible outcomes of a random experiment is called a sample space and each outcome is called a sample point." and probability is defined as $$P=\frac{n(E)}{n(S)}$$ here $n(E)$ is number of favourable outcomes in the sample space and $n(S)$ is the number of elements in sample space, this definition seemed perfect to me until I encountered a very trivial problem of probability:

Find the number of ways of drawing exactly 1 red ball if two balls are drawn at random (without replacement) from a bag containing 2 red and four black balls (assume balls of the same colour are identical): to solve this I wrote the sample space, ie: $\text{{(R,R)(R,B)(B,R)(B,B)}}$, here $n(E)$ should be $\text{{(R,B),(B,R)}}$ so the probability comes out to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

But I know from intuition (and also from the answer) that this is incorrect,

Where am I going wrong?,

I know this is a silly question to ask, but this problem is not letting me sleep, please help.

Comment: "*and probability is defined as...*"  No.  This is not how probability is defined.  It is a very special circumstance to have this relation be true and it will only be true in general when each outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur.  There are many circumstances, this one included, where outcomes are not equally likely to occur.

Comment: Your definition of spaces is almost correct. But your calculations are wrong. You need to calculate all possible pairs of type $\{(r,b),(b,r)\}$. Note that there are more than 2 ways to take one red ball and one black ball. And also JMoravitz is correct. That's a partial way to determine probability measure. It only deals with counting measure.

Comment: Now... in order to use counting techniques, we can often *choose to reimagine* the problem in such a way that allows us to work with an equiprobable sample space (*a sample space where each outcome is equally likely*).  This is a *choice*, one which you will learn with experience how to make efficiently.  Here, we can choose to imagine that each ball were uniquely numbered (*even if they are not in reality numbered or distinguishable in any way other than where in space they currently reside*).  We can also choose to imagine the balls were drawn in sequence rather than simultaneously if prefer

Comment: With such choices to reimagine made, your sample space will instead be much larger: $\{\{R_1,R_2\},\{R_1,B_1\},\{R_1,B_2\},\{R_1,B_3\},\{R_1,B_4\},\{R_2,B_1\},\cdots,\{B_3,B_4\}\}$, but in doing so, each outcome will be equally likely to have occurred and you can again use counting techniques and ratios of set sizes to find the probability.  Note that some probability questions, such reimaginings to get to an equiprobable sample space will be impossible, so direct calculations will be necessary.  For example, flipping a biased coin who lands on heads with probability $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz so if the balls of the same colour were distinct then also the answer would have been the same?

Comment: Yes, the answer to the *probability* question will be the same whether the balls of the same color were distinct or identical.  The answers to the *counting* questions however may be different.  (*Note the difference between "find the probability" and "find the number of ways"*)

Comment: Thank you very much @JMoravitz, now my concept is clear!